# Training a machine learn model with more than one file

Tags: python, keras, training-data

I'm kind of new in working with deep learning, and specially with more than one file per time. I have a folder of files, and I want that my model(LSTM) files train with all that files.

Can I just use model.fit() inside a loop of a path files? Would it make sense? Or I should try to concatenate that into a single array? In this case the problem is the features have different ranges.

```
import os 
rootdir = '/content/Data' #looping over files
for filename in os.listdir('/content/Data'):
 with open(os.path.join(rootdir, filename)) as f:   
  A = np.loadtxt(f)     model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, 
  epochs=20, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: LSTM models have a different nature and require embedding. You should look for an existing model and see how it is built to create your own.

Comment: My idea is  a kind o simple: given a series that tends to a value, determine that final value. Do you have any idea of models that I could try? It seems like mostly of machine learninf classics methods would not work.

Comment: Well, posting questions on Stack overflow isn't for recommending architectures or so. It's intended to help those who are sticking with specific problems such as errors, coding logic, etc. Your problem requires some research. :)